# Use of TimePicker

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to create an app that send a notification (with a customised text) when the time is the same the user inserted in the timePicker, but the notification doesn't appear at all.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val UniqueID = 47245
    timePicker.setIs24HourView(true)
    button1.setOnClickListener {
        if((Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY == timePicker.hour) && (Calendar.MINUTE == timePicker.minute)) {
            var notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "M_CH_ID")
            notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            notification.setTicker(editText.text)
            notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            notification.setContentTitle("Notifica")
            notification.setContentText(editText.text)
            var ringtone: Uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
            var intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            notification.setLights(Color.RED, 2500, 1000) 
            notification.setSound(ringtone)
            notification.setAutoCancel(true)
            var notManager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notManager.notify(UniqueID, notification.build())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the API level of the device you're running this on, and what's your target API?

Comment: The device is huawei p10 lite, so api 24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) and [`Calendar.MINUTE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#MINUTE) are constant values in the `Calendar` class to use with the [`get()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)) method. To get the current hour and minute, you can do the following:

```
 val now = Calendar.newInstance()
 val hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
 val minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
```

These are the values that your `if` check should be against.